# Return FieldValue Where FieldName Equals Value and ID Equals Number

Tags: sql, joomla

I am creating a dynamic dropdown within Joomla 3x utilizing a database query and I cannot get the results to group within the same option (FieldValue - FieldValue - FieldValue). Each result returns as its own option.

What I am trying to accomplish is this: 
Within the table submission_values - If the FieldName equals CDR-Number, 501c3, and amount - return the FieldValue of each FieldName for every SubmissionId where the FormId equals 18.
[image: table to query]
My current code:

```
//<code>
$items = array();
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$items[] = "| - Select Charity Details - [c]";
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
->select(array('a.FieldValue', 'a.FieldName', 'a.SubmissionId', 'a.FormId'))
->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submission_values', 'a'))
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__rsform_submissions', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.SubmissionId') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.SubmissionId') . ')')
->where($db->quoteName('a.FormID') . ' = 18 ')
->where($db->quoteName('a.FieldName') . ' IN ("amount" , "501c3", "CDR-Number")')
->order($db->quoteName('a.SubmissionId') . ' DESC');

$db->setQuery($query);

$query->dump();
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($results as $row) {
$value = $row->FieldValue; 
$label = $row->FieldValue; 
$items[] = $value.'|'.$label; 
}

return implode("\n", $items);
//</code>
```

Returns 6 results instead of 2. 
[image: Dropdown Results]

I need the results to return CDR-001: One80 Place - $1,000.00 and CDR-002: March of Dimes -$2,000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest pivoting your table then concatenating into a single-column result set.

I also see no compelling reason to JOIN `#__rsform_submissions` so I have removed it from my snippet.

Code: (tested locally)

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select("CONCAT(
                        MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'CDR-Number' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END),
                        ': ',
                        MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = '501c3' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END),
                        ' - ',
                        MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'amount' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END)
                      )")
            ->from("#__rsform_submission_values")
            ->where("FormID = 18")
            ->where("FieldName IN ('CDR-Number', '501c3', 'amount')")
            ->group("SubmissionId DESC");
// echo $query->dump();  // if you want to see the rendered query
$db->setQuery($query);
echo "<pre>";
try {
    var_export($db->loadColumn());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Select Query Syntax Error " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
    // use $e->getMessage() only while debug and page is not viewable by public as a matter of security
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'CDR-002: March of Dimes -$2,000.00',
  1 => 'CDR-001: One80 Place - $1,000.00',
)
```

Here is a recent answer at JoomlaStackExchange where I suggest/explain the pivot technique: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23921/12352

If you would have posted your question on JoomlaStackExchange, I would have found it sooner and could have delivered this solution to you yesterday.  In the future, please post your Joomla questions over there.

Comment: Query works exactly like I wanted it to. However, I am catching issues trying to capture the array in the dropdown select > option.

Comment: I was able to add the results by removing the echo / try and add the following:
$results = $db->loadColumn();
$items = $results;
$items[] = "| - Select Charity Details - [c]";

Thanks for your help greatly appreciated! I hope this helps others too. I saw similar posts, but it wasn't exactly clear as to how they rendered the results into the dropdown and my attempts were not successful.